# Querying pandas against each other

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a df against another, something like this:

```
df1:
     myval
0    1.2
1    3.5
2    5.7
3    0.4

df2:
     thrsh
0    0.4
1    5.5
2    1.0
3    0.0
```

I would love to query this way:

```
(df1['myval']>df2['thrsh'])
```

so to come out with a new df which would have all the combinations:

df3:

```
thrsh  myval 
0      0    true
       1    true
       2    true
       3    false
1      0    false
       1    false
       2    true
       3    false
```

basically creating a 3rd dimension out of the combination of the 2 dfs.
as for now the result is "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects".

any idea? 
thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) both columns, so get same `Multindex` in both, so possible compare:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.index, df2.index], names=['thrsh','myval'])
m = df1['myval'].reindex(mux, level=1) > df2['thrsh'].reindex(mux, level=0)
print (m)
thrsh  myval
0      0         True
       1         True
       2         True
       3        False
1      0        False
       1        False
       2         True
       3        False
2      0         True
       1         True
       2         True
       3        False
3      0         True
       1         True
       2         True
       3         True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: jezrael, thank you so much, this works perfectly. I have now to try applying this simultaneously across multiple cols to filter of the actual dfs! :P